# Why am I getting a crash saying "Fatal Error: Array Index out of range"?

Tags: xcode, swift

Hi I am trying to have an app that adds a point in a mapView, sends it to to a ViewController and when the user taps on a place in the tableView it should send back to the point in the mapView but this is where I get the error, my app crashes and I get "thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_1386_invop subcode=0x0)" on the line that says:

```
    let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue
```

here is my code

```
if activePlace == -1 {


        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

            } else {



    let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue

    let longitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lon"]!).doubleValue

    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)

    self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = places[activePlace]["name"]

    self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)






    //save data start

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places") // saves data to NSUserDefaults

    //stop save data

}
```

and here is how active place is 'made'

```
var activePlace = -1



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        activePlace = indexPath.row

        return indexPath

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "newPlace" {

            activePlace = -1


        }



@IBAction func addCurentLoc(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        var newCoordinate2 = self.Map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

        var location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate2.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate2.longitude)

        //title = "new address"

        //try change order start

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate2

        annotation.title = title


        annotation.coordinate = self.Map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in


            var title = ""

            if (error == nil) {

                if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                    var subThouroughfare:String = ""
                    var thouroughfare:String = ""

                    if p.subThoroughfare != nil {

                        subThouroughfare = p.subThoroughfare!

                    }

                    if p.thoroughfare != nil {

                        thouroughfare = p.thoroughfare!

                    }

                    title = "\(subThouroughfare) \(thouroughfare)"


                }

            }

            if title == "" {

                title = "Added \(NSDate())"

            }

            places.append(["name":title,"lat":"\(newCoordinate2.latitude)","lon":"\(newCoordinate2.longitude)"])

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate2

            annotation.title = title

            self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }

        self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation);


        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
                     viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!{
            if(annotation is MKUserLocation){
                return nil;
            }

            // let pinView: Void = mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,reuseIdentifier:"MyIdentifier");
            return pinAnnotationView;

        }






    }
```

The print statement says this :

```
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

how could I solve this issue? thanks !

Comment: what else do you do to the `activePlace`? How do you change its value? Where exactly does it crash? Debug it! Set a breakpoint, add `print`-statements!

Comment: Agreed that you need to debug, but I have a question. Where do you increment `activePlaces?` a quick glance at your code, to me it seems like it just stays -1. Which means anytime you try to access it your going to get the error `index out of range`

Comment: Thanks for the help, this might be a stupid question but how do I find out the value of active places is at the line ?

Comment: Setting a breakpoint and checking the value in the debugger console or saying `print(activePlaces)` in code everytime before you use it.

Comment: But i suggest making it easier to read like so 
`print("activePlaces current value is \(activePlaces)")

Comment: it just gives me this: activePlaces current value is (activePlaces)
activePlaces current value is (activePlaces)
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)

Comment: Oh my god in condition activePlace == -1 so he is trying to get array item with -1 index

Comment: I have active places current value is 1 in the console, after adding 1 place with looks good (to me ) @NSGangster

Answer (score 0):

> "Fatal Error: Array Index out of range"?

This error occurs due to the places do not contain any object on index you are asking.

Example :

```
    var places = [0,1,2,4] 
    // next line is crash because array do not contains any item on 5 index
    places[5]
```

Try to check what you are using in this variable :`activePlace`

Comment: The only times I feature `activePlace` are the ones I have in the question and I can't understand why it is empty.

Comment: Man activePlace == -1 so you try to reach array with -1 index

Comment: That is only when no places are added

Comment: And you try to get -1 element from array that contains non - elements